# Generate dynamic LINQ expression based on array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, expression

I am using LINQ exprssion to query customers and filter them by state names. I have following query which works fine till the time I have 4 items in my statesArray.

```
public void GetCustomersForSelectedStates(string[] statesArray)
{
    var customers = _repo.GetAllCustomers();
    var filteredCustomers = from CUST in customers
    join ST in States on CT.Tag_Id equals ST.Id                       
    where CUST.ID == customer.ID  && (ST.Name == statesArray[0] ||ST.Name ==statesArray[1] || ST.Name== statesArray[2]||ST.Name =statesArray[3])

    //Do something with customers

}
```

I want following exprssion to be created dynamically:

```
(ST.Name == statesArray[0] ||ST.Name ==statesArray[1] ||    
 ST.Name== statesArray[2]||ST.Name =statesArray[3])
```

For example , create the dynamicQuery like below

```
var dynamicQuery = "(";
var dynamicQuery = "(";
for (int i = 0; i < statesArray.Count(); i++)
    {
        dynamicQuery += "ST.Name =="+statesArray[0];
        if(i==statesArray.Count())
        dynamicQuery+=")"
    }
```

and then use it something like following,

```
//Psuedo code
var customers = _repo.GetAllCustomers();
    var filteredCustomers = from CUST in customers
    join ST in States on CT.Tag_Id equals ST.Id                       
    where CUST.ID == customer.ID  && Expression(dynamicQuery)
```

Comment: Why not just use `statesArray.Contains(ST.NAME)` ?

Comment: @JohnWu, Thanks , this works , was making this unnecessarily complicated. But will keep the question open (to know how to generate expression dynamically)

Comment: alternatively you can use recursive method concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that *via dynamic expressions* basically means building a tree of:

```
(x.Foo == val0 || x.Foo == val1 || x.Foo == val2)
```

You can do that like this:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where<T, TVal>(Expression<Func<T, TVal>> selector,
    IEnumerable<TVal> values)
{
    Expression result = null;
    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        var match = Expression.Equal(
            selector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(val, typeof(TVal)));

        result = result == null ? match : Expression.OrElse(result, match);
    }
    if (result == null) return x => true; // always match if no inputs

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(result, selector.Parameters);
}
```

with example usage:

```
string[] names = { "a", "c" };
var predicate = Where<Customer, string>(c => c.Name, names);
```

You can then use this `predicate` in the `IQueryable<T>.Where` extension method.

To combine it in your case, first do your *regular* LINQ:

```
var customers = _repo.GetAllCustomers();
var filteredCustomers = from CUST in customers
join ST in States on CT.Tag_Id equals ST.Id                       
where CUST.ID == customer.ID;
```

Now *as a separate step* apply the extra filter:

```
customers = customers.Where(predicate);
```

---

What this does is accept an *input* lambda of the form `c => c.Name`, then reuses the `c.Name` *body* for each `c.Name == {val}`, and reuses the `c` *parameter* as the parameter for the lambda we're creating. Each value from `values` becomes a typed constant. The `Expression.Equal` gives us the `==` test. The `OrElse` is the `||`, noting that if `result` is `null`, this is the **first** item, so we just use the match expression itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another join

```
var customers = _repo.GetAllCustomers();

var filteredCustomers = from CUST in customers
    join ST in States on CT.Tag_Id equals ST.Id  
    join SA in statesArray on ST.Name equals SA // No need dynamic expression now          
where CUST.ID == customer.ID 

//Do something with customers
```

Comment: I would expect this to either fail (bad), or work by performing the join in-memory locally (much worse)

Comment: @MarcGravell based on _repo.GetAllCustomers() - we are locally already. But yes, if we join to DB through EF with such join - we'll fail.

Comment: that doesn't follow; I'm guessing that the repo has something like; `public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers() => db.Customers;` - it doesn't suggest we're fetching anything. Also, the question is tagged linq-to-sql, strongly suggesting this approach

Comment: @MarcGravell that's a situation where we have "it depends". If we are locally already - join will be short and simple. In some situations (with small amount of data in repo) this works fine. If we have EF (standard for .NET) - we'll fail. If we have other IQueryable - we'll be depend on provider. Your answer is much more universal and elegant, plus it correlates with a question better.